# Varios filtros com VBA

Tags: vba

Galera boa tarde

preciso realizar um filtro em uma coluna da planilha, coletar um determinado valor e excluir o resto da mesma coluna.
Tenho esse codigo porem ele funciona apenas para 1 aba.
Preciso de um cod para mais de 10abas... alguem poderia me ajudar?
segue o cod

'executar
 Sub filtro_01()

```
Dim lLin As Long
```

'Caminho para salavar o arquvivo que sera gerado

```
fname1 = (sCaminho & "\" & Format(data, "yyyy") & _
"\" & Format(data, "mmmm")) & "\" & Format(data, "dd") & _
"\" & "nome do arquvio"
```

' seleção das abas

```
Worksheets(Array("Plan1")).Copy
```

' Filtro Plan1

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Altere o nome da planilha abaixo:
With Sheets("Plan1")
    For lLin = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(lLin, "E") = "Cell 02" Then .Rows(lLin).Delete
        If .Cells(lLin, "E") = "Cell 03" Then .Rows(lLin).Delete

        'Desafoga os processos pendentes do Windows a cada 100 linhas iteradas:
        If lLin Mod 100 = 0 Then DoEvents
    Next lLin
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente, se esse código funciona para uma aba, é só iterar em várias, o que pode ser feito assim:

```
Dim Plan as Worksheet

For each Plan in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets ' Pressupondo que o arquivo com as planilhas é o que está ativo quando esta função for chamada; se não for, fazer referência ao arquivo de excel adequado.
    'Aqui você cola seu código que funciona para uma planilha,
    ' só que usando a variável Plan para as referências.
    ' Por exemplo:
    Plan.copy ' Em vez de Worksheets(Array("Plan1")).Copy
    With Plan ' Em vez de With Sheets("Plan1")
    'Pelo código acima, acho que só as duas linhas acima precisam
    ' de adaptação, as outras não mudam nada.

Next Plan
```

Só uma dúvida: você não colocou seu código todo aqui não, né? Pergunto isso por dois motivos:

1) Você copia a planilha sem colar em lugar nenhum, de forma que a instrução `Copy` ficou perdida/inútil;

2) Você exclui diversas linhas da planilha Plan1 do arquivo original, mas não compila o resultado em outro lugar. Se você rodar esse código iterando todas as planilhas, na forma descrita acima, vai terminar com o arquivo original sem as linhas excluídas, mas ainda dividido em planilhas diferentes. Para unificá-los em uma planilha só, poderia copiar o conteúdo de cada Planilha (propriedade `UsedRange` de cada planilha) e colar tudo em uma planilha só.

**EDIT SOBRE A PROPRIEDADE `USEDRANGE`:**
`UsedRange` é uma propriedade do objeto Planilha (`WorkSheet`) que retorna uma range com a área em uso. Portanto, para saber o endereço do intervalo em uso na planilha, você poderia usar `Plan.UsedRange.Address`, que te retorna uma string com o endereço em uso na planilha Plan. Para descobrir a última linha, pode usar `Plan.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row`.
Contudo, tome cuidado com a propriedade `UsedRange`. Ela costuma resetar a cada vez que é utilizada, então não é interessante fazer múltiplas referências ao UsedRange de uma planilha. Se for necessário usar muitas vezes, é melhor você atribuir a UsedRange a uma variável do tipo Range e trabalhar com esta, ou pesquisar de outras formas (dá uma procurada ou pergunta aqui no StackOverflow, pois esse edit todo já não tem a ver com o assunto principal dessa pergunta).

Comment: primeiramente obrigado pela ajuda, o cod acima esta apresentando um erro ....... ERRO 438 ( O Objeto nao aceita esta propiedade ou método ) 

Sobre suas dúvidas vamos lá.
1) Com os dados filtrados e copiados eu crio  um novo arquivo e colo.  
2) Como utilizo esse metódo? ( UsedRange) 

Obs: Dentro da coluna " E " tenho tres tipos de celulas preciso copiar apenas a "cell 01" e excluir a " cell 02" "cell 03 ". Copiar a planilha atualizada e gerar um novo arquivo com os novos dados

vou te mostrar o cod abaixo de como estou fazendo

Comment: Sobre o erro, foi uma falha minha: o correto é `For Each Plan in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets`. Editei a resposta. Sobre o UsedRange, vou editar a resposta também.

Comment: Por fim, sobre o item 1, o que eu estranhei é que você copia a planilha ANTES de fazer as alterações, sacou?

Comment: Show! Muito obrigado Cesar